# Handle Marshall error from CopyFileEx

Tags: c#, exception, task, marshalling

For backup our users data prolly  10000 users i plan use this wrapper but since its kinda dangerous in term of lost user data i realy need catch all copy error (file exist,autorisation etc....).

here the wrapper

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PROBTP_BACKUP2.Model
{

    public static class FileEx
    {
        public static Task CopyAsync(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
        {
            return CopyAsync(sourceFileName, destFileName, CancellationToken.None);
        }

        public static Task CopyAsync(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, CancellationToken token)
        {
            return CopyAsync(sourceFileName, destFileName, token, null);
        }

        public static Task CopyAsync(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, IProgress<double> progress)
        {

            return CopyAsync(sourceFileName, destFileName, CancellationToken.None, progress);

        }

        public static Task CopyAsync(string sourceFileName, string destFileName, CancellationToken token, IProgress<double> progress)
        {
            int pbCancel = 0;
            CopyProgressRoutine copyProgressHandler;
            bool bSuccess = true;
            if (progress != null)
            {
                copyProgressHandler = (total, transferred, streamSize, streamByteTrans, dwStreamNumber, reason, hSourceFile, hDestinationFile, lpData) =>
                {
                    progress.Report((double)transferred / total * 100);
                  Console.WriteLine((double)transferred );
                    return CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
                };
            }
            else
            {
                copyProgressHandler = EmptyCopyProgressHandler;
            }
            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            var ctr = token.Register(() => pbCancel = 1);
            var copyTask = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                 bSuccess = CopyFileEx(sourceFileName, destFileName, copyProgressHandler, IntPtr.Zero, ref pbCancel, CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS);
                 token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();


                }

                finally
                {

                    ctr.Dispose();

                }
                if (!bSuccess)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(bSuccess);
                    string errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                    Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);

                }
            }, token);

            return copyTask;
        }

        private static CopyProgressResult EmptyCopyProgressHandler(long total, long transferred, long streamSize, long streamByteTrans, uint dwStreamNumber, CopyProgressCallbackReason reason, IntPtr hSourceFile, IntPtr hDestinationFile, IntPtr lpData)
        {
            return CopyProgressResult.PROGRESS_CONTINUE;
        }

        #region DLL Import

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CopyFileEx(string lpExistingFileName, string lpNewFileName,
           CopyProgressRoutine lpProgressRoutine, IntPtr lpData, ref Int32 pbCancel,
           CopyFileFlags dwCopyFlags);

        delegate CopyProgressResult CopyProgressRoutine(
            long totalFileSize,
            long totalBytesTransferred,
            long streamSize,
            long streamBytesTransferred,
            uint dwStreamNumber,
            CopyProgressCallbackReason dwCallbackReason,
            IntPtr hSourceFile,
            IntPtr hDestinationFile,
            IntPtr lpData);

        enum CopyProgressResult : uint
        {
            PROGRESS_CONTINUE = 0,
            PROGRESS_CANCEL = 1,
            PROGRESS_STOP = 2,
            PROGRESS_QUIET = 3
        }

        enum CopyProgressCallbackReason : uint
        {
            CALLBACK_CHUNK_FINISHED = 0x00000000,
            CALLBACK_STREAM_SWITCH = 0x00000001
        }

        [Flags]
        enum CopyFileFlags : uint
        {
            COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS = 0x00000001,
            COPY_FILE_RESTARTABLE = 0x00000002,
            COPY_FILE_OPEN_SOURCE_FOR_WRITE = 0x00000004,
            COPY_FILE_ALLOW_DECRYPTED_DESTINATION = 0x00000008
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

here the launcher on click button

```
public async void StartProcessing(string test)
        {
            var progressIndicator = new Progress<double>(ReportProgress =>
            {
                fileName = ReportProgress.ToString();
                totalPercent = (int)ReportProgress;
            });
            CancellationToken cts = new CancellationToken();
            await Task.Run(() => FileEx.CopyAsync(@"input.rar","C:\cop\output.rar", progressIndicator));

        }
```

lets say i clik 3 time here the output (the file aalready exist for test purpose)

-False
-Descripteur non valide
-False
-Le fichier existe
-False
-Le fichier existe

which i translate by 
-Invalid descriptor
-file exist
-file exist

well you get it i don't know why i get at first an "Invalid descriptor" 
and in a second time i'm not sure i will catch any error this way.

so if someone can help add a serious error handling code i'm happy

ps: i know someone will ask it ,why i not use copyTo or robocopy etc..
its cuz we need progress or user will prolly kill process on loooooooooooong file copy thinking application has crashed.(tough if i'm not feel well with the wraper i plan copyTo().

Comment: i don't know another way to catch errors form marshalled functions (besides lastWin32Error), but you can always calculate hashvalues from the files which will be copied and check them afterwards.

Comment: yes only Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() will do it but i think its more about how and where i put it that is wrong. its anormal at first i get this Invalid descriptor error.

Comment: have you seen this? https://web.archive.org/web/20130304214632/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163851.aspx

Comment: it heped me yeah thank secret was to catch marshall exception rigth at execution. if(!CopyFileEx(sourceFileName, destFileName, copyProgressHandler, IntPtr.Zero, ref pbCancel, CopyFileFlags.COPY_FILE_FAIL_IF_EXISTS))
                 {
                     string errorMessage = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message;
                     Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
                 }

Comment: Well, that's too much of a good thing.  Asynchronicity is very helpful to avoid your UI getting unresponsive.  You already got that from using async/await.  But then you do it *again* with a CopyAsync() method.  That does not make it twice as good.  Actually makes it many, many times worse, you've now got dozens of threads all trying to access the disk at the same time.  Makes copying a *lot* slower.  Use File.Copy() for the trivial solution.

Comment: yeah i got   var copyTask = Task.Run(() => that i would do sync but i don't see yet how my progress wil work without it